# Edit text with clear button auto hide?

Tags: android, android-edittext

Does anyone know how to make a EditText with a button to clear the text within the EditText own?
I need to do this so that when you start typing the text, the button appears at the end of EditText style 'X', and when you clean the 'X' button disappears.

Here is my layout...

```
    <!-- Editext for Search --> 
                    <EditText               
                         android:id="@+id/inputSearch"                               
                         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                         android:hint="Search"
                         android:background="@drawable/headlinebtn"
                         android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                         android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium" 
                         android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_action_search"
                         android:layout_centerVertical="true" /> 



                     <ImageView
                          android:id="@+id/clearbtn"      
                          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                          android:layout_marginRight="10dp"      
                          android:src="@drawable/X"
                          android:layout_alignParentRight="true"  
                          android:layout_centerVertical="true" />
```

I have done  till clear  edit text by clicking drawable button(x)..My problem is this button is showing every time..I want to do like while type it should be foucasable ..otherwise it is hidden..
Any Ideas  guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just check the editText's length, when it is greater than 0 then set imageView visibility VISIBLE...otherwise INVISIBLE or GONE

```
 editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                int arg3) {
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1,
                int arg2, int arg3) {
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable name) {
            if(editText.getText().toString().lenghth()>0){
    imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
 }else{
 imageView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}

        }
    });
```

Comment: Almost Correct but Imagview is initially not hidden once we enter and clear edit text it works...again come back same problem it appears

Comment: Thank u buddy..Just one more clarification..While entering text in edit text it covering enter space..i mean it taking space after the button also. Thank You

Comment: sorry!! i didn't get you.

Comment: I just want single line edit text...i have give it singleline=true..But if we type long text it is taking space after the button...I just need to do space till the imageview button

Comment: if you talking about the button then you have to change your xml coding....
one simple trick is give paddingRight in edittext....

Comment: i meant..my edit text taking space after by clear button...while i enter long text

Comment: or just add 
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/clearbtn" in editText